# Split each string in a list into digit and non-digit parts

Tags: python, string, list, element, subtraction

I have this list of strings:

```
x = ['+27', '05', '1995 F']
```

I want some code that outputs this:

```
['+', '27', '05', '1995', 'F']
```

I was thinking about using the `.split()` function on the last element so I wrote this code:

```
x=['+27', '05', '1995 F']
x[2]=x[2].split()
```

This outputs:

```
['+27', '05', ['1995', 'F']]
```

How do ensure the 2nd element is not a sub-list, and instead output this?

```
['+27', '05','1995','F']
```

Should I use `insert` and `del`?

I wrote this for the first element using `insert` and `del`:

```
x=x.split("/")
x.insert(0,x[0][0])
x.insert(1,x[1][1:])
del x[2]
```

This outputs:

```
['+', '27', '05', '1995 F']
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I fixed a __lot__ of capitalization, indentation, spelling and formatting errors in your post. Please take a bit more effort for future questions to keep quality high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> x=['+27', '05', '1995 F']
>>> [''.join(g).strip() for s in x for k, g in groupby(s, str.isdigit)]
['+', '27', '05', '1995', 'F']
```

This works by splitting each string in `x` into groups of characters based on whether they're digits or not, then joining those groups back into strings, and finally stripping whitespace from the resulting strings.

As you can see, unlike the other solutions presented so far, it splits '+27' into '+' and '27' (as your question says you want).

Comment: whoops I missed the + 27 part.  confusing question

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['+27', '05', '1995 F']
l = []
[l.extend(e.split()) for e in x]
print l
```

and checkout this for the fancier one [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one quick solution:

```
x=['+27', '05', '1995 F']
finlist=[]
for element in x:
    for val in element.split(" "):
        finlist.append(val)
print finlist
```

Or:

```
x=['+27', '05', '1995 F']
finlist=[]
for element in x:
    finlist.extend(element.split(" "))
print finlist
```

Answer (score 1):

"How do ensure the 2nd element is not a sub-list output this?"
Use `extend` for that:

```
In [32]: result = []

In [34]: inp = ['+27', '05', '1995 F']

In [35]: [result.extend(i.split()) for i in inp]
Out[35]: [None, None, None]

In [36]: result
Out[36]: ['+27', '05', '1995', 'F']
```